# How can i write a list of list in excel to only one column row by row?

Tags: python, excel, list, xlsxwriter

I have a list of list with datas and i would like to write it to one column row by row but my excel file when i do it looks like this:

[image]

I want that to look like this:
[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
import xlsxwriter

all_list = [['aaa1','aaa2','aaa3'],
            ['bbb1','bbb2','bbb3'],
            ['ccc1','ccc2','ccc3']]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('qweqwe.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for row,data in enumerate(all_list):
    worksheet.write_column(row,0,data)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you use for writing is `worksheet.write_column(starting_row, starting_column, data)`. When you iterate over your `all_list` with `for row, data in enumerate(all_list):` then you'll get iterations with:

- `row = 0`, `data = ['aaa1','aaa2','aaa3']`
- `row = 1`, `data = ['bbb1','bbb2','bbb3']`
- `row = 3`, `data = ['ccc1','ccc2','ccc3']`

So your starting row will be 0, 1, 2 in order and you're overwriting what you've already written.

You can flatten your `all_list` with something like:

```
from itertools import chain

worksheet.write_column(0, 0, chain.from_iterable(all_list))
```

`chain.from_iterable(all_list)` will flatten the original into an iterator over `['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'bbb1', 'bbb2', …]` so you can write them all with a single `write_column`.

Comment: Or `chain.from_iterable(all_list)` so you don't have to "splat"-expand the list first; better for performance and memory usage.

Comment: @aneroid oh, completely forgot about that! Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways you could dot it.

### Loop

Initialize row to 0 and increment it by the length of each set of data.

So the first set of data will start at row 0, then the next set will go below that and so on.

```
import xlsxwriter

all_list = [['aaa1','aaa2','aaa3'],
            ['bbb1','bbb2','bbb3'],
            ['ccc1','ccc2','ccc3']]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('qweqwe.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
for data in all_list:
    worksheet.write_column(row, 0, data)
    row += len(data)
```

### List comprehension

You could also do it by 'flattening' the list of lists using list comprehension.

```
import xlsxwriter

all_list = [['aaa1','aaa2','aaa3'],
            ['bbb1','bbb2','bbb3'],
            ['ccc1','ccc2','ccc3']]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('qweqwe.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = [item for lst in all_list for item in lst]            

worksheet.write_column(0, 0, data)

workbook.close()
------------------
```